# How to use a variable to construct command

Tags: xcode, swift, swift2, xcode7

I have a variable in Xcode that I need to use to construct another command. How to I combine this? This is the concept

I have a variable named "activechannel1" and buttons Overlay1 - Overlay12

I want to set the image of a particular button and the button will depend on the value of activechannel1. All the numbers correspond to file names so I am trying to do this.

Let's say that

```
ActiveChannel1 = 6 // This changes and represents which button I want to change
```

I am trying to do this but am getting a consecutive statement error:

```
Overlay"\(ActiveChannel1)".image = UIImage(named: "y\(ActiveChannel1)")
```

Which I want to essentially yield:

```
Overlay6.image = UIImage(named "y6")
```

Answer (score 0):

You can't dynamically "type" variable names. You *can*, however, access them in such a way that a variable can change which one you use.

Classes you might find useful (note that there are changes to how you use these in Swift):
[NSArray](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/Cocoa/Reference/Foundation/Classes/NSArray_Class/index.html)
[NSDictionary](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/Cocoa/Reference/Foundation/Classes/NSDictionary_Class/index.html)

Given X as the number (in the form of a string here):

For `OverlayX`, you can use an array.

```
let overlays = [Overlay1, Overlay2, /*...*/]
```

Access the right variable using the indices 0-11.

For `yX` use `NSString(format:)`.

```
//use %d for int
let imageName = NSString("y%@", X - 1) //%@ is Obj-C format for id IIRC, I'm not sure if it changes in Swift
overlays[X - 1].image = UIImage(named: imageName)
//or, in a single line
overlays[X - 1].image = UIImage(named: NSString(format: "y%@", argList: X - 1))
```

Note that this code in untested.
Also note that I use Objective-C more than Swift. If someone comes across this and finds the syntax incorrect, please comment or edit my post.

Comment: When you access the overlays with` overlays[1]` you are getting `Overlay2` back. So in this case it should be `overlays[X-1].image = ...` since you are counting from 1.